# Compile the xlslib on Windows issues

Tags: visual-c++, xlslib

I tried to compile the xlslib on Windows Visual Studio ,I have failed,I have read readme files when I have extracted the archeive file of xlslib-package-2.5.0.zip.It tells me I simply open the sln file which locate in contrib folder.I just following this step.then I tried to compile it on Visual Studio ,but many errors occured,I have tried built it on VS 2008 and VS 2013,it doesnt works at all.here is my errors belows

```
error   3   error C2380: type(s) preceding “sheet_notes” (constructor wit`h return type, or illegal redefinition of current class-name?)`   c:\Users\abcd\Desktop\xlslib-package-2.5.0\xlslib\xlslib\src\xlslib\note.h  46  xlslib_lib
error   4   error C2208: “xlslib_core::sheet_notes”:  no members defined using this type    c:\Users\abcd\Desktop\xlslib-package-2.5.0\xlslib\xlslib\src\xlslib\note.h  46  xlslib_lib
error   5   fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation   c:\Users\abcd\Desktop\xlslib-package-2.5.0\xlslib\xlslib\src\xlslib\note.h  46  xlslib_lib
error   7   error C2380: type(s) preceding “sheet_notes” (constructor wit`h return type, or illegal redefinition of current class-name?)`   c:\Users\abcd\Desktop\xlslib-package-2.5.0\xlslib\xlslib\src\xlslib\note.h  46  xlslib_lib
error   8   error C2208: “xlslib_core::sheet_notes”:  no members defined using this type    c:\Users\abcd\Desktop\xlslib-package-2.5.0\xlslib\xlslib\src\xlslib\note.h  46  xlslib_lib
error   9   fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation   c:\Users\abcd\Desktop\xlslib-package-2.5.0\xlslib\xlslib\src\xlslib\note.h  46  xlslib_lib
```

I ever post a thread on xlslib discussion for help,but there's only a people who is David Hoerl,he replied that he is not familiar with Windows platform,he is only familar with MAC platform,so I don't know What to do.I  do not too familar in C++ ,any idea for these issues?
any tips or helps would be apperaciated
regards
Ken

Comment: format your question pls!

Comment: HI,I have modified my Question,is this looking better?

Comment: Go through this please! http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve